# How can a table of user be built from multiple SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a list of about 200 emails that I want to search on my database. The goal is to build a table with the following format:

```
email      | ID
-----------+-----
a@b.com    | 2
c@d.com    | null
e@f.com    | 42
```

Where the `email` column is the email being searched and `ID` is the ID of the user in case it exists in my users table, with `null` being the result in case it is not found.

How can I retrieve these results from my list of emails? Can multiple `SELECT` statements be used, or it's better if I use a scripting language?

My users table can be simplified to having two columns, `id` and `email`. Just like the result referenced above.

Comment: it's better if you use a scripting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with all the e-mail addresses and left join the users table on the e-mail address.

```
CREATE TABLE emails
             (email varchar(256));

INSERT INTO emails
            (email)
            VALUES (a@b.com),
                   (c@d.com),
                   (e@f.com);

SELECT e.email,
       u.id
       FROM emails e
            LEFT JOIN users u
                      ON u.email = e.email;
```

An index on `users (email)` might help with performance.

Comment: for thathe must convert first the list into a table, it us much simpler to do that directly in the application

Comment: @nbk: Well, "simpler" might be opinion based here... Besides I don't see much difference here -- loop through the list to build and fire a `SELECT` for each entry or build a list for an `IN` operation or loop through it to append it to the `INSERT` and fire that once after the loop -- it always needs one loop. But my approach is likely a lot faster than firing 200 independent statements or using `IN` with 200 entries.

Comment: i find the question unclear, as i don't kniow what lust and where it is coming from, that made me hesitate to give an answer like you

Comment: @nbk: Hmm, the question could be presented in a better way, I agree. But I don't think it's unclear. It's an edge case I think.

Comment: @nbk Sorry by being unclear in the question. The list is just a plain text list. It's easy to me to transform that (in my text editor) to multiple selects or just in a quick-and-dirty script, since this is basically very simple and only supposed to build a CSV file. So, all in all, I could have solved it in multiple ways but the motivation to this question was seeing if there was a more solid way which I was missing. This solution is particularly interesting and an exact match to that -- it's not something I had thought before. Thank you both very much

Comment: Also, I don't plan to reuse this technique, this is just a quick thing that popped up from my team -- we have a list of emails, collected from the newsletter, and I'm supposed to build this list to check if they also are active users of the service. If the goal was automating and possibly reusing this late, I'd definitely implement it directly in the application.